# How to pass modal id to controller and model for using in query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am making a modal using looping data from the database on my project but I want to fetch all data in a database by selecting query `GROUP BY` color `where id = modal id` but my controller can't get the modal id which makes it error on selecting. please help me to fix it... thank you

this is the View code :

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table table-sm" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
   <thead class="warna-header">
       <tr>
          <th rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">Tipe</th>
            <th colspan="3" class="text-center bg-danger">1</th>
            <th colspan="3" class="text-center bg-warning">2</th>
            <th colspan="3" class="text-center bg-success">3</th>
            <th rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;" class="text-center">ACTION</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>  
   <?php foreach ($st_mobil as $st_mbl) : ?>                    
    <tr>                                
       <td style="font-size:12px;color:black;"><?php echo $st_mbl['jenismobil']; ?></td>
       <td style="font-size:12px;color:black;text-align:center;"><?php echo $st_mbl['beli1']; ?></td>
       <td style="font-size:12px;color`enter code here`:black;text-align:center;"><?php echo $st_mbl['jual1']; ?></td>
       <td style="font-size:12px;color:black;text-align:center;"><?php echo $st_mbl['sisa1']; ?></td>
       <td class="text-center">
           <a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-sm view_detail" data-toggle="modal" title="Edit Data" data-target="#ViewStockMobilModal<?php echo $st_mbl['id']; ?>">
           <span class="icon text-white-10">
           <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
           </span>
           </a>
       </td>
    </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table>

-- Modal View
<?php foreach ($st_mobil as $st_mbl) : ?>
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="ViewStockMobilModal<?php echo $st_mbl['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
aria-labelledby="ViewStockMobilModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="jenismobil" name="jenismobil">
                    <font color=white><?php echo $st_mbl['jenismobil']; ?></font>
                </h5>
                <button type="button" class="close text-white" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
                        <thead class="btn-primary">
                          <tr>
                                <th style="font-size:12px;" class="text-center bg-danger">ST</th>
                                <th style="font-size:12px;" class="text-center bg-danger">BK</th>
                                <th style="font-size:12px;" class="text-center bg-danger">BJ</th>
                           </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <?php foreach($view_detail as $vdt) : ?>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-size:12px;color:black;"><?php echo $vdt['warna']; ?></td>
                                <td style="font-size:12px;color:black;text-align:center;"><?php echo $vdt['st_in_1']; ?></td>
                                <td style="font-size:12px;color:black;text-align:center;"><?php echo $vdt['st_out_1']; ?></td> 
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </table>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is the controller :

```
$data['st_mobil'] =  $this->db->get('st_mobil')->result_array();
$id = $this->input->get($id); // i want to get the id of my modal 
$data['view_detail'] = $this->stock_model->get_view_modal($id);
```

This is my model :

```
public function get_view_modal($id)
    {
        $query = "SELECT `id`,`jenismobil`,`warna`,`st_in_1`,`st_out_1`,`st_sisa_1`,`st_in_2`,`st_out_2`,`st_sisa_2`,`st_in_3`,`st_out_3`, st_sisa_3`
                    FROM `st_mobil`
                    GROUP BY `warna`
                    WHERE `id` = '$id'
                    ";
        return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: You have some errors on those codes, like a missing single quote in `$data[st_mobil] =  $this->db->get('st_mobil)->result_array();` or the extra $ in `$public function get_view_modal($id)` both should result in sintax errors.

Comment: sorry but i write it wrong only here not on my real project ....but the real problem is why my $id didn't have any result?

Comment: I think I'm missing something, because I can't see a link, button or action that sends data to controller.

Comment: thats what i want to ask cause i dont know how to send data id to controller

Comment: Add something like `<a href="controller.php?id=here_the_id">Send data to controller</a>` inside the modal.

Comment: This href trigger the modal
<a href="" class="btn btn-success btn-sm view_detail" data-toggle="modal" title="Edit Data" data-target="#ViewStockMobilModal<?php echo $st_mbl['id']; ?>">

This is the modal that trigger by href above
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="ViewStockMobilModal<?php echo $st_mbl['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" 
aria-labelledby="ViewStockMobilModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

and where should i put this <a href="controller.php?id=here_the_id"> ??

Comment: I'm pretty sure that link is the one that shows the modal.

Comment: yeah that links is the one that show the modal but in my condition my i foreach  id to open the modal but i cant fetch data with select group inside to fetch all data by id

Answer (score 0):

When you getting the id 
$id = $this->input->get('id'); // this should corrected like this.

Comment: but $id = $this->input->get('id'); // didn't get the modal id cause i'am using looping for modal id

Comment: try something like this                                                                                           <a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Controller/Function?id=<?php echo $st_mbl['id']; ?>">
                        
                    </a>

Comment: where should i put this code?

when i var_dump the $id the result is NULL

Comment: inside your <?php foreach ($st_mobil as $st_mbl) : ?>  you are using a href right. try to replace it to something like above.